# Relational database design

Tags: relational-database

I'm trying to understand entities, tables and foreign keys.  I have the following:-

AnObject - I have identified this as an entity type.

```
ID (Primary Key)    
Description    
State    
DependsOn    
Creator
```

Now State has only two values it can be `[Alive, Dead]`.  However it could possibly have another in the future.  It can however only be one or the other but it will likely change between the two.

Question:

> Should State be its own entity type?  Would it be an entity type or
>   just a table?  Should State have a foreign key to AnObject or vice
>   versa?  EG

State

```
ID (PK)
Description
AnObject_ID (Foreign Key references AnObject)
```

Question: The DependsOn attribute of AnObject can have multiple values of other AnObject entity types.  Obviously a field cannot have multiple values but I'm not sure how to model this?

The Creator attribute of AnObject also takes up a strict number of values [Fred, Jim, Dean].  Should I have an entity type (table) for a Creator with a foreign key to AnObject ID?  So, A Creator can create, 0, 1, m AnObjects but AnObject can only have one creator?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

State could just be an `enum` field, unless you need users to be able to add other State values via a user interface, in which case you could use a lookup table (one-to-many relationship) as you suggested. I don't know what database you're using, but here's some info on the `enum` type in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html.

If you use a lookup table, then AnObject should have a field called StateID that points to the desired row in the State table.

It sounds like DependsOn is a many-to-many relationship. For that you will need a join table, e.g.:

```
Table: Dependencies

Primary key (called a "composite key" because it's made up of more than one field):
    AnObjectParentID
    AnObjectChildID
```

I've assumed that the dependencies are needed for a parent-child relationship but if that's not the case you might want to name the table or fields differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra tables for enumeration values with a foreign key from AnObject to it. State will probably be best represented as a single field of type varchar not null. You can have the primary key for a table be a varchar field - they don't have to be int type.

This will constrain the values but allow you to use reasonable syntax to query the thing (i.e. WHERE state = 'Alive' (although in this case I think you're prematurely abstracting things - I'd keep it simple and just have a simple bool column IsDead).

DependsOn is a one-way attribute (you presumably can't have A depend on B and also B depend on A). The real issue here is how you're intending to query these items and how many of them there will be. If you want to pull out the whole chain of dependencies at once and the chain is long, you want to avoid doing hundreds of individual queries to do that. What is your use case?